# How to check if the input is a valid integer without any other chars?

Tags: c++, validation, integer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    cout << "5 + 4 = ";
    while(!(cin >> x)){
        cout << "Error, please try again." << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    if (x == (5 + 4)){
        cout << "Correct!" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Wrong!" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I check if the user inputs a valid integer? In this program I wrote above, if the user inputs `9`, it should be correct, however, if the user inputs `9a` for example, it should return an error, but it doesn't for some reason. How can I correct it?

How I did it using cin.peek()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    bool ok;
    cout << "5 + 4 = ";

    cin >> x;

    while(!ok){
  cin >> x;

  if(!cin.fail() && (cin.peek() == EOF || cin.peek() == '\n')){
  ok = true;
  }
  else{
  cout << "Error, please try again." << endl;
  cin.clear();
  cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  }
    }

    if (x == (5 + 4)){
  cout << "Correct!" << endl;
    }
    else{
  cout << "Wrong!" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could read a string, extract an integer from it and then make sure there's nothing left:

```
std::string line;
std::cin >> line;
std::istringstream s(line);
int x;
if (!(s >> x)) {
  // Error, not a number
}
char c;
if (s >> c) {
  // Error, there was something past the number
}
```

Comment: You could also just `peek()`.

Comment: You generally want to skip trailing white space as well, since the user can't see it, and won't understand why there is an error if it occurs.

Comment: @JamesKanze There shouldn't be any trailing whitespace - I'm using `>>` to extract the string (as the OP did), not `getline()`.

Comment: Ah, yes.  But then that doesn't correspond to what he seems to be trying to do (since he skips to the end of the line when there is an error).

Answer (score 3):

```
bool isIntegerNumber(const std::string& string){
  std::string::const_iterator it = string.begin();
  int minSize = 0;
  if(string.size()>0 && (string[0] == '-' || string[0] == '+')){
    it++;
    minSize++;
  }
  while (it != string.end() && std::isdigit(*it)) ++it;
  return string.size()>minSize && it == string.end();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a line oriented input, so you should probably be using
`getline`.  Something like:

```
bool
getIntFromLine( std::istream& source, int& results )
{
    std::string line;
    std::getline( source, line );
    std::istringstream parse( source ? line : "" );
    return parse >> results >> std::ws && parse.get() == EOF;
}
```

should do the trick.

Using this, your loop would be:

```
while ( !getIntFromLine( std::istream, x ) ) {
    std::cout << "Error, please try again." << std::endl;
}
```

Note that this technique also means that you don't have to worry
about clearing the error or resynchronizing the input.

Answer (score 3):

For the reason this happens, take a look at this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/):

> Extracts and parses characters sequentially from the stream to
>   interpret them as the representation of a value of the proper type,
>   which is stored as the value of val. Internally, the function accesses
>   the input sequence by first constructing a sentry object (with
>   noskipws set to false). Then (if good), it calls num_get::get (using
>   the stream's selected locale) to perform both the extraction and the
>   parsing operations, adjusting the stream's internal state flags
>   accordingly. Finally, it destroys the sentry object before returning.

Then observe the behavior if you attempt something like this:

```
int x = 0;

cin >> x;
std::cout << x << std::endl;
std::cout << cin.good() << std::endl;

g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -O3 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && echo "900a100" | ./a.out
// Output:
// 900
// 1
```

If you input "a100" instead, it outputs:

```
0
0
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;

if ( std::all_of(input.begin(), input.end(), std::isdigit) )
{
     //input is integer
}
```

Refer this :

[C++ Fix for checking if input is an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767800/c-fix-for-checking-if-input-is-an-integer)

Comment: Thus "-10" is not a valid integer ? :)

Comment: Error: `all_of` was not declared in this scope. I need code for C++, not C++11 also for both signed/unsigned integers.

Comment: @user2699298 C++11 *is* C++. I guess you mean you need C++03.

Answer (score 1):

One I have seen that works for some situations is:

- Read the input as string.  `cin >> str`
- Decode to number: atoi, or sscanf, or stringstream, etc.
- print the number into a string (using sprintf or stringstream)
- check if its equal to read string. (using strings ==, not char*)

Quick and simple to do. Uses the Cin>>str word breaking rules, accept negative numbers, rejects overflowing numbers. But it does reject "+10", which in somesituations you are happy wiht, and in some you are not.

Comment: If you can use regex, that last part is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use C++11 (and your compiler has full regex support), you can also use the `<regex>` library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    std::pair<int, bool> value = std::make_pair(0, false);
    std::cout << "5 + 4 = ";
    while (!value.second)
    {
        while (!std::getline(std::cin, line))
        {
            std::cout << "Error, please try again." << std::endl;
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }

        if (!std::regex_match(line, std::regex("(\\+|-)?[[:digit:]]+")))
        {
            std::cout << "Error, please try again." << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            value = std::make_pair(std::stol(line), true);
        }
    }

    if (value.first == (5 + 4))
    {
        std::cout << "Correct!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Incorrect!" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```