# How can I validate an integer input

Tags: c++, validation

For example I have the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int test = 0;
    cout << "Please input a number:";

    while(!(cin >> test))
    {
        cout << "Invalid input";
    }

    if(test  == 1)
    {
        cout << "Test is 1";
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something
    }
   return 0;
}
```

If I input `1abc` to the test variable it still continues to process the `if` statement even though the input is wrong. How could I ignore all the input made and just accept pure numbers in it?

Comment: The input is not wrong: it is a number followed by some other characters.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654636/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-number-with-c) should help. Read the input as a string (with `std::getline`) and then test if that is a number or not.

Comment: [How to check if the input is a valid integer without any other chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20287186/608639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getline`, `find_if_not`, and `isdigit` to check if an entire line is a valid integer or not. This will loop until it reads an integer:

```
std::string number;
while (std::getline(std::cin, number) && number.end() !=
       std::find_if_not(number.begin(), number.end(), &isdigit))
    std::cout << "gitgud!";
```

`getline` will read the input up to the newline, and put it in the string. `find_if_not` and `isdigit` will find the first non-digit character. If there are none (meaning it is a valid integer), it will return the `end` iterator.

Comment: Thanks it fixed the problem, but is there anyway to not use strings?

Comment: @CodingisFun Strings are the easiest way. You could use `std::cin.getline` to read into a `char[]`, or make your own loop to read characters one at a time, if you really wanted.