# How do I accept 0 as an integer and not a bool value?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to validate user input for integers only. My code works fine except when the user inputs 0. It doesn't consider it an integer, and it thinks the value is false. Here's a brief example of how I'm coding this project....

```
int main ()
{
    int num;
    cout  << "Please enter an integer: ";
    cin >> num;
    cout << endl;

     while (! num)
     {
          cout << "That is not an integer.\n";
          return;
     }
}
```

If the user inputs 0, I get sent into the while loop even though 0 is an integer.

Comment: `while (!num)` means to enter the loop if `num` is `0`

Comment: Your checking logic is broken. `num` is always an integer.

Comment: You should check the return value of `cin >> num` instead.

Comment: You are getting integer only, you only use `num` for condition check and it behaves as expected. If you explain you use case then it might be more helpful.

Comment: `num` is always a int. If someone enters a string, `cin >> num;` will throw.

Comment: So what should I use instead? I'm new to coding, sorry. Should I try while (cin >> !num)?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20287186/1025391 http://stackoverflow.com/q/35954159/1025391 http://stackoverflow.com/q/16934183/1025391

Comment: @TobiasR.: Only if you tell the steam library to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *expression* `!num` is `true` if, and only if, `num` is 0. So your implementation is buggy.

The easiest thing to do is to use something like

```
if (!(std::cin >> num)){
    std::cout << "That is not an integer.\n";
}
```

If you want to validate the input yourself then consider reading in a `std::string` and checking if that can be converted to an integer. This is surprisingly non-trivial since the possible values an `int` can take are so platform dependent (some systems have a range as small as -32767 to +32767).

If you can, use `boost::lexical_cast<int>(num);` where I've upgraded `num` to a `std::string` type. (The header you need is `<boost/lexical_cast.hpp>`).

Comment: thanks! I must have been tired when writing this code, because I've definitely validated input this way in the past. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

In c++ the built-in `int` type doesn't have any optional validity to it like it does in some other languages: "`!num`" just means "`num==0`" and not "`num` does not exist".

However C++17 has `std::optional` template, which can turn your vanilla `int` into exactly what you originally expected!

All you need is some simple template magic to make it work with `istream`:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits, class T >
basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& operator>>( basic_istream<CharT,Traits>&& st,  
                                         std::optional<T>& value )
{
    T res;
    st>>res;
    value = (st)?res:{};
    return st;
}
```

Come to think of it, STL should provide that overload from the box.

Now all you need is to replace your `int num` with `std::optional<int> num` and voila - your code works as intended.

*Seriously though, just use Bathsheba's solution.*